# CosmosDB SQL: how to use ARRAY_CONCAT or ARRAY(select distinct ...) as aggregate function?

Tags: group-by, azure-cosmosdb, aggregate-functions, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a collection in Azure CosmosDB where each document has 2 fields, say

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
{"a":1,"b":3}
{"a":2,"b":5}
```

and I want to return a set of possible values of B for each A, like this:

```
[{"a":1, "b":[2,3] },
 {"a":2, "b":[5]   }]
```

Trying `SELECT c.a, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT c.b FROM c) FROM c GROUP BY c.a`
I receive the error

`Property reference 'c.b' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Same for `ARRAY(select value c.b from c)`; and `ARRAY_CONCAT` does not look like an aggregate function.

Are there ways to do it without aggregating client-side?

Comment: I don't think it is possible because Array is not aggregate function anyway which means it can't used with group by. Maybe you have to implement on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, this is not supported in Cosmos Db so far. Because `Array` is not [aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-aggregates) anyway which means it can't used with `group by`.

So, i suppose that you need to retrieve the data sort by `a`. Then loop the result to produce the `b` array mapping to the duplicate `a`.

Answer (score -1):

For, Distinct values of b (output is in string format and values of b are comma separated)
SELECT a, String.Join(",", ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT b)) AS list FROM c;

You can also use below, but the output format is not readable
SELECT a, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT b) AS list FROM c;

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Comment: Ummm, interesting, are you sure this is CosmosDB syntax? I know U-SQL (of Azure Data Lake) supports ARRAY_AGG, but never seen it in CosmosDB. Also queries you provided give either "identifier `a` couldnt be resolved" or "Property reference `c` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." if I correct `a` to `c.a.`